# Are Euclidean domains exactly the ones which we can define "mod" on?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) $E$ is an integral domain where, for any $a, b \in E$, we can write:

$$a = bq + r$$

with either $r = 0$ or $f(r) < f(b)$, where $f$ is the valuation function attached to $E$.

Can I define the binary operation $\bmod$ such that $a \bmod b = r$ for all Euclidean domains? Will it always behave the same way as the mod function on $\mathbb{Z}$ that I'm used to?

What got me wondering was the observation that I can do this on the Euclidean domain $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by using quotient rings:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\psi_{x^2 + x} &:: \mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2 + x \rangle\\
\psi_{x^2 + x}(x^2 + x + 5) &= x^2 + x + 5 + \langle x^2 + x \rangle = 5 + \langle x^2 + x \rangle\\
\end{aligned}
$$

So $r = 5$ and $x^2 + x + 5 \bmod (x^2 + 5) = 5$, as you would expect. It also works for multiplication.

Comment: Side Note: ​ ​ ​ I found it non-obvious that there are _any_ rings which non-trivially admit such modular reduction. ​ Can you come up with one _before_ reading the answer to [the question I asked about that](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1731897/57159)? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: I'm a bit confused -- what do you mean by non-trivial? The example that got me wondering about this was $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: By "non-trivial", I mean [[not isomorphic to the integers] and [has an ideal that's neither just {0} nor the whole ring]]. ​ $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ doesn't work because , for example, what would [x-1 mod x] be? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: Are you talking about the mod function or binary relation? As a function, I would say that $x - 1 \mod x = -1$.

Comment: I'm talking about the mod function, for which outputs should be non-negative, at least when both inputs are positive. ​ ​

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you say, you’re using the binary function “mod” of the computer scientists. But in mathematics, one finds that this function is of very limited utility, and we use the *equivalence relation* $a\equiv b\pmod I$ instead. It’s read, “$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $I$”, and it’s a sentence that will be either true or false.

To your specific question, consider the Euclidean domain $\Bbb Z[i]$, the Gaussian integers. If you take a complex modulus like $\zeta=6+3i$, it makes perfect sense to say whether two Gaussian numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are congruent modulo $\zeta$, namely you check to see whether $\beta-\alpha$ is a multiplie of $\zeta$ by another Gaussian number. But there is no good and consistent way of defining a “mod” function here. You can make up an artificial “mod” function in this situation, but it will be neither good nor consistent.

Comment: Nice counterexample. I guess I'm having a hard time relating this to my knowledge that the binary mod operation does work over $\mathbb{Z}$. (If you choose the smallest positive, I guess). What does $\mathbb{Z}$ have that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ lacks in this case?

Comment: @AlfredYerger: $\Bbb Z[i]$ certainly *is* a UFD. $5$ is not irreducible in $\Bbb Z[i]$, so $5 \times 1$ is not a valid factorization into irreducibles.

Comment: Another question I have here: if I choose a convention for mod here, like "the positive real one" in what ways is the resulting function inconsistent?

Comment: @EliRose : ​ There's not necessarily a positive real one. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, precisely. To define  “mod” function, you must choose beforehand a full set of representatives of the equivalence classes (cosets) of your relation. I chose my example precisely so that there would be no such set consisting only of real Gaussian integers. One possible set would be all $m+ni$ with $0\le m<5$ and $0\le n<3$, but this is truly artificial, as I think one’ll notice after trying to work with it for a while.

Answer (score 7):

To your title:  No. Any ring works for a mod operation, you just make things the standard coset way. Let $I\subseteq R$ be an ideal. Then we define

> $$a\equiv b\mod I\iff a-b\in I.$$

And this is a well-defined equivalence relation.

For the integers this reduces to

$$a\equiv b\mod n\iff a-b\in (n)\iff a-b=nk$$

for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.

So to the question in the body (which is not the same thing) as to if we can define mod for EDs:  yes you can, but they're not the most general setting.

Comment: Cool! Can we also construct this definition via quotient rings in the manner I was trying to show?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, $R/I$ is what a quotient ring is, and it literally means "things of $R$ up to equivalence mod $I$." Perhaps you mean with the remainder? Remainders is only a thing for EDs, that's their defining property. The mod operation is much more general than this, though

Comment: In my abstract algebra class, we defined $R/I$ as a group of cosets, so the connection to mod is new to me. (It's a lot nicer). So it seems like you're saying that $R/I$ is isomorphic to the group of equivalence classes of elements of $R$ mod $I$, given the definition above. Is that right? What does "remainder" mean in the way that you use it here?

Comment: @EliRose There is no notion of remainder in general rings, if there were they would all be EDs. The term "mod" is used in groups for things modulo normal subgroups, and in rings as rings modulo ideals, i.e. it's always for coset spaces for special subgroups (in groups normal, in rings ideals). You seem to think it is "connected" to the classical notion of "mod," but in reality this notion is the generalization of mod, it's not connected to it, it literally **is** it.

Comment: Okay, I take your point. (and I wish it had been introduced to me that way).

Comment: So it seems that, for any ring in which $a - b \in I$ for some ideal $I$, we have $a = bq + r$ for some $q, r$. Then the only trick is proving $f(r) < f(b)$, which only holds in Euclidean domains (where we can appropriately define such an $f$). Is that the case?

Comment: Actually the congruence relation can be defined on a lot of algebraic structures, for the quotient group $G / H$ (where $H \leq G$) is exactly the quotient set of the congruence relation $a mod b \iff ab^{-1} \in H$

Comment: @EliRose no, there is no bq+r outside of the ED arena, that's the whole point of an ED, what does $bq+r$ even mean if you don't have a notion of $r< b$? And as mattecapu says, this is only for rings we're talking about, mod operations are **very** general.

Comment: Ah -- it wasn't clear to me that in any ring, for a given $a, b$ one can find $q, r$ (with no restrictions on $q, r$) such that $a = bq + r$, but now I see that one can take $q = 0$ and $r = a$. So the special part is really $f(r) < f(b)$, as you say.

Comment: @EliRose yes, exactly. The point of EDs is that there is sort of a way to compare sizes, which we lost from not having just the integers. Without that, it's a non-starter.

Answer (score 4):

In a Euclidean domain, there is no requirement that $r$ be uniquely determined by $a$ and $b$, so you cannot define mod in the way you proposed.

Comment: Relating this answer with Adam's below: there's no need to pick canonical representatives to talk about mod. The point is that it's often better to think of mod as a ternary relation, than as a binary operation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, but the original post talks about defining the "binary operation" mod, in which you *are* picking a canonical representative.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't meant as a disagreement with your answer, more a comment to the OP: that while you do need to talk about representatives to view mod as a binary function, everything we actually use mod for goes through fine if it's just a relation. Edited for clarity (and +1 btw).

Comment: Don't we ordinarily pick a canonical representative when we say "$12$ divided by $5$ has a remainder of $2$", though? I guess in that case I'm choosing the smallest positive pair $(q, r)$ such that $a = bq + r$.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm just choosing the only pair with both positive -- is there another that works? Are there other Euclidean domains where the choice is not so clear?

Comment: @EliRose Even in $\mathbb{Z}$, there is another reasonable choice, which is to choose the remainder with the smallest absolute value.  So e.g. if b=7 then the possible remainders are -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3.

Comment: @Ted: I understand there are many possibilities, and Lubin's answer has shown me that there is no good choice in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, but I'm having difficult understanding what the issue is with the grade-school use of "$12$ divided by $5$ has a remainder of $2$". Is it inconsistent, or is it consistent over $\mathbb{Z}$ but not when extended to other Euclidean domains (if so, why?)?

Comment: @EliRose There is nothing wrong with that. You can define mod over any Euclidean domain, if you're satisfied with arbitrarily *choosing* a (q,r) satisfying a=bq+r (and smaller norm), then defining (a mod b) = r.  But this operation is useless.  Even over  $\mathbb{Z}$, mod is an awkward operation to work with. The reason it's sort of useful in $\mathbb{Z}$ is that r is uniquely determined under the mild restriction r>0.  In F[x] (F a field), it's uniquely determined under the restriction that r is monic. Beyond that, I can't think of any cases where mod is useful as an operation.

Comment: @Ted: I suppose that in the grade-school context, it's an operation defined on the positive integers only. Then we impose $r > 0$ without qualms. So we didn't really define mod over a ring, only over a subset of that ring. The equivalent subset of $F[x]$ would be the monic polynomials, it seems? I wonder if there is such a subset for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Now rethinking what I just said, since it seems we'd have at least as many problems with the positive polynomials (even monic) as we would with positive integers.