# Is there a non-trivial ordered ring with an "integer-esque" modulo function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

(I'm inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1729926/57159).)

Is there a [not-necessarily-commutative non-[simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring) o[rdered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) with a 1 that's not equal to 0]

which is *not* isomorphic to the integers but *is* such that

for all positive elements m, for all elements x, there is a least

non-negative y such that x-y is in the (two-sided) ideal generated by m

?
(An isomorphism between an ordered ring and the integers is automatically order-preserving.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ring of rational polynomials with integer constant coefficient should do. (Ordered in the natural way by the sign of the leading coefficient).